# Contar 0s rodeados de 1s - SQL

Tags: sql, string, count

Necesito una query o una función que cuente los 0s que se encuentran rodeados de 1s. Estoy probando con `string_split` pero me devuelve una columna.

Por ejemplo dado estos string el resultado deseado es:

```
String1 = '10101101' -> Result=3
String2 = '11111001101' -> Result=1
String3 = '01111111111' -> Result=1
```

Solo necesito buscar los patrones '101' o '01' en el caso de que se encuentre al principio del string.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Buenas, te encuentras en StackOverflow en Español, por favor traduce tu  pregunta a este idioma, para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Perdona, ya está traducida.

Comment: Si termina en 10 ¿También cuenta o ese no?

Answer (score 1):

Es un poco raro hacer esto en sql cuando sería mucho más fácil conseguirlo en un lenguaje de programación.

Dicho eso, seguramente te valga

```
(len(value) - len(replace(value,'101',''))) / len('101')
```

Ejemplos:

```
'10101101' -> len 8 -> replace 01 -> len 2 -> 8 - 2 / 3 -> 2
'11111001101' -> len 11 -> replace 11111001 -> len 8 -> 11 - 8 / 3 -> 1
```

Y aplicaría lo mismo para `10` el problema es que al contar 2 formatos distintos tienes que tener en cuenta que uno de ellos también cuadra con el otro. Y que al quitar carácteres para contar puede que crees nuevos casos que también cuadrarán

ejemplo:

para `01011` si remplazamos primero `101` queda `01` con lo cual también cuadrará con la segunda regla y dará 2 en vez de 1

Si lo hacemos a la inversa también dará 2 pero por razones muy distintas..

Answer (score 1):

Esto se puede hacer fácilmente con una tabla de números para poder hacer las cadenas de 2 o 3 caracteres que buscamos. Si no sabes lo que es una tabla de números, es simplemente una tabla con una sola columna con cada fila numerada. En este caso, estoy creando una tabla al vuelo para reducir lectura de disco.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Contar0sRodeadosde1s(
    @String varchar(8000)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS(  --Generamos 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( --Generamos 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( --Generamos 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas (suficientes para varchar(8000))
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP (LEN( @String) - 1) --Restringimos la cantidad de filas para solo calcular las necesarias.
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 n --numeramos cada fila iniciando en cero
    FROM E4
)
SELECT COUNT(*) Ocurrencias
FROM cteTally
WHERE SUBSTRING( @String, n, 3) IN( '101', '01'); --Solo el primer valor tendrá 2 caracteres porque empezamos en cero

GO
```

Después, para llamarla desde una consulta, solo necesitamos usar `CROSS APPLY`. Dejo un ejemplo que incluye la creación de la tabla para que cualquiera lo pueda probar fácilmente.

```
DECLARE @Tabla TABLE( String varchar(100));

INSERT INTO @Tabla
VALUES('10101101'),('11111001101'),('01111111111');

SELECT *
FROM @Tabla
CROSS APPLY dbo.Contar0sRodeadosde1s(String) c
```